# How many percentage of packages (main restricted universe multiverse) are taken from Debian?

Tags: debian, development

I'm just curious to know how many packages or percentage of packages does Ubuntu take from Debian for all the packages that reside in main, restricted, universe and multiverse.

Also, if you link some reference or source that is more credible, it would be awesome.

Comment: No such statistics have ever been gathered.  It's safe to assume *most* of the repos are inherited from Debian and then changes applied on the Ubuntu side as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS it is partially presented on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal :

> Derived from Buster
>
> - 27259 packages with differences (132 needing attention)
> - 1109 packages only in Buster
> - 3466 packages only in Focal

Separating in pockets is very difficult.